# How can we achive dynamic schema validation in DataPower?

Tags: validation, xsd-validation, ibm-datapower

Requirement:
Dynamic schema validation.

The request URL will contain the function name in query string.

```
http://DataPowerIP:Port/CD_HTML/AOL.jsp?function_id=YY_TD_ICT_CER_CREATE
```

DataPower will have multiple XSDs in its file management. Need an XSLT which can help t0 fetch the query string from the URL and extract the function id`YY_TD_ICT_CER_CREATE`.

Next it will match function id name with the XSD file name `YY_TD_ICT_CER_CREATE.xsd` and if match found will do the scema validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XSL, you can get your URI via `dp:variable('var://service/URI')`.  Write your code to parse out the function_id into an `xsl:variable`.  Then set a DataPower context variable with the name of the schema file to be used for validation:

```
<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/this/schema-file'"
    value="concat('local:///my-schemas/', $function-id-value, '.xsd')"/>
```

The next step in your policy after this XSL Transform step will be a validate step.  In the place where you normally specify a static local XSD, specify the context variable instead:

[image: DataPower Validate using var]

Comment: Let me try this. Will get back to you with the results.

Comment: Tried it and I was able to do what I was intended to do. Thanks for the lead. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

alternmatively you can do Schema validation in stylesheet processing URL-in directly via the [dp:schema-validate()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.5.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/schema-validate_metadatafunction.html) extension function.

But I don't really see the value of allowing Schema validations against a client specified Schema, at least in general. Schema validation should make sure that input data is valid. In case client can point to any Schema (eg. via "http://..." URL for the Schema) bad input does not get rejected.

Hermann.